# How to Move all files within a single directory to multiple directories?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, cp

I have a directory that contains files I need from a calculation (6.00-film2) and I have 10 other directories, each with 10 sub-directories that I would like these files copied into. Is there an easier way of doing this rather than doing

```
cp -r 6.00-film2/ 5.5-film/5.5-1
```

100 times.

The directory 5.5-film contains 5.5-1, 5.5-2, 5.5-3, 5.5-4, 5.5-5, ..., 5.5-10. I need the files from 6.00-film2 to be copied into each of the 10 directories above, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`cp` can copy from multiple sources, but **can't** copy to multiple destinations. See `man cp` for more info.

The only bash command that I know which can copy/save to multiple destinations is `tee`.

You can use it as follows:

```
tee ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/test.txt < ~/test.txt
```

Note that `tee` also writes the input to the standard output (stdout). So if you don't want this, you can prevent it by redirecting standard output to `/dev/null` as follow:

```
tee ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/test.txt < ~/test.txt >/dev/null
```